# 405 method not allowed(Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, post, http-headers

I am trying to hit a third party end point via Rest client in Java but I am getting "405 method not allowed" exception. The end point I am trying to hit is  "Post" and it works fine when being hit from Postman. Following is my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    headers.add(CHIRAGH_CLIENT, AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
    headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    headers.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ChiraghConstants.BCI_AUTH_TOKEN);
    headers.add("user-agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
    HttpEntity<BlockChainSaveBidDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(event.getSaveBid(), headers);
    CompletableFuture res = restTemplate.postForObject(
            ChiraghConstants.BCI_BASE_URL + ChiraghConstants.BCI_AUCTION_BID_START +"/"+ event.getTokenId() + ChiraghConstants.BCI_AUCTION_BID_END , entity, CompletableFuture.class);
```

Comment: referring to this:

event.getTokenId() + ChiraghConstants.BCI_AUCTION_BID_END

is it normal that you don't add the "/" as well?

Comment: Off-Topic: sending Accept twice isn't helpful here.